# Front end Wordpress post live preview

Tags: wordpress, post, live-preview

Does anyone know of any plugins or resources for creating of a live preview for front-end submitted Wordpress posts?

My site has a front-end submission page with several text fields, radio buttons, and an image uploader. I would like to have a div to the right of these fields that displays a live preview using the page's template. I've haven't been able to find anything helpful online.

[Photo of my front end post submission page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQzQi.png)

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a plugin that accomplishes this specific thing, but have you considered JS? You could use Javascript to grab the values from the form fields and add them to your `<div>` each time a user interacts with one of the fields.